# How can I install Hubstaff when I double click it a gedit window will open?

Tags: system-installation

How to install `Hubstaff` giving a script file named `Hubstaff-1.2.1-79428cc.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Copy it to your home folder.

Run these two commands.

```
chmod +x Hubstaff-1.2.1-79428cc.sh
./Hubstaff-1.2.1-79428cc.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to CLI mode described in the first answer, here how you can do it GUI.

Once you have downloaded the file, you will need to install it by going into file Properties->Permissions and check the “Execute” box.

[image]

Now double click on the file, You will then be prompted to run the installation. Follow the instructions until the app get installed successfully.

[image]

Then you will be prompted to enter your registered email and password.

[image]

Now you should see Hubstaff’s timer widget. From there you can select a project from the list to start tracking time.

[image]

You can also right-click on the widget and a dropdown menu will be displayed.

[image]

All credits goes to owner: [Install and Sign-in into Linux Desktop Client](http://support.hubstaff.com/install-and-sign-in-into-linux-desktop-client/)